# Which projection: Map from South Tyrol (Italy)

Tags: coordinate-system, italy

I need to find out what projection this base-map has for digitizing the information that was drawn on it. It's from South Tyrol (South Tirol) in Italy. I have the following information:

Title: **Provincia di Bolzano / Provinz Bozen**
Year: It was published **1980**, so it could be anything before that

It has this overview:
[image]

Next to it is has this code: **4 III NO-B**

And the page number: **Foglio 74 / Blatt 74**

The x-coordinates are given like this: **E=1650000**

And the y-coordinates: **N=5183000**

At the bottom of the map it says (some sort of copyright notice):

```
  Questo supporto consente solo copie a luce fredda

  Cartogr. Autorizz. A norma di legge
```

And then it says:

```
  E.I.R.A.

  Ente Italiano rilievi aerofotogrammetrici

  Rilievo aerofotogrammetrico eseguito con strumenti "Galileo-Santoni"
```

Edit:

I did some research and it might be a Gauß-Boaga (Gauss-Boaga) or Roma 40 projection, but I'm not sure yet.
Link: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proiezione_di_Gauss-Boaga

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The x-coordinates are given like this: **E=1650000**
>
> And the y-coordinates: **N=5183000**

These coordinates are expressed in `EPSG:3003` (`Monte Mario / Italy zone 1`), while **[Foglio 4](http://www.igmi.org/wfs_server?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=serie100&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326&FILTER=%3Cogc%3aFilter%3E%20%20%3Cogc%3aPropertyIsEqualTo%3E%20%20%20%3Cogc%3aPropertyName%3Eid%3C/ogc%3aPropertyName%3E%20%20%20%3Cogc%3aLiteral%3E3980%3C/ogc%3aLiteral%3E%20%20%3C/ogc%3aPropertyIsEqualTo%3E%20%3C/ogc%3aFilter%3E)** is an IGMI topographic map at scale 1:100k. The code **4 III NO-B** reports the reference of the marked element at scale 1:5k, i.e. Foglio 4 (1:100k), 3rd quadrant (1:50k), North Western (1:25k), part B (1:5k).